# How can I get the most recent different event?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what `mytable` looks like:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
|      Time       | EventType | MachineName | UserDisplayName  |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| 7/22/2014 6:52  | CONNECTED | MACH-10     | alice.brown      |
| 7/22/2014 6:52  | PENDING   | MACH-10     | alice.brown      |
| 7/22/2014 9:09  | PENDING   | MACH-2      | mike.hensworth   |
| 7/22/2014 6:58  | CONNECTED | MACH-2      | mike.hensworth   |
| 7/22/2014 6:57  | PENDING   | MACH-2      | mike.hensworth   |
| 7/22/2014 7:00  | CONNECTED | MACH-3      | will.garden      |
| 7/22/2014 6:59  | PENDING   | MACH-3      | will.garden      |
| 7/22/2014 5:30  | PENDING   | MACH-3      | will.garden      |
| 7/22/2014 11:20 | CONNECTED | MACH-4      | kent.clark.admin |
| 7/22/2014 11:20 | PENDING   | MACH-4      | kent.clark.admin |
| 7/22/2014 9:28  | CONNECTED | MACH-5      | inigo.montoya    |
| 7/22/2014 9:28  | PENDING   | MACH-5      | inigo.montoya    |
| 7/22/2014 9:15  | PENDING   | MACH-123    | inigo.montoya    |
| 7/22/2014 12:37 | CONNECTED | P-002       | joseph.smith     |
| 7/22/2014 12:36 | PENDING   | P-002       | joseph.smith     |
| 7/22/2014 9:43  | CONNECTED | P-005       | penny.pennyworth |
| 7/22/2014 9:41  | PENDING   | P-005       | penny.pennyworth |
| 7/22/2014 5:41  | CONNECTED | P-006       | thor.zeus        |
| 7/22/2014 5:40  | PENDING   | P-006       | thor.zeus        |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

The situation is people (UserDisplayName) are logging into machines (MachineNames).  Eventtype PENDING is the start of the logging in, EventType CONNECTED is successful connection.

Essentially, I need the average amount of time it takes a user to log into a machine.  I don't have a good way to connect the `PENDING` status to the `CONNECTED` status, so I'm trying to calculate the time difference between the `CONNECTED` status and the most recent `PENDING` EventType for a given `MachineName`.

I don't know how to do that, and that's what this question is about.

But I'm also having problems I'd like to overcome and identify.

1. (For example, `inigo.montoya`) Sometimes users start a `PENDING` on one machine, then give up when it takes to long, and start a second `PENDING` on a second machine.  There's no `CONNECTED` listed to close that first `PENDING` event.  I'd like to identify these occurrences.
2. (For example, `MACH-3`) Sometimes `PENDING` never becomes `CONNECTED` on the machine, and somehow the users are able to start a second `PENDING` which works as intended.  I'd like to identify these occurrences.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results for the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
with successes as
 (select x.userdisplayname,
         x.machinename,
         x.time as connection_time,
         y.time as pending_time,
         datediff(mi, y.time, x.time) as mins_between
    from mytable x
    join mytable y
      on x.userdisplayname = y.userdisplayname
     and x.machinename = y.machinename
   where x.eventtype = 'CONNECTED'
     and y.eventtype = 'PENDING'
     and y.time = (select max(z.time)
                     from mytable z
                    where z.userdisplayname = y.userdisplayname
                      and z.machinename = y.machinename
                      and z.time < y.time))
select y.userdisplayname, y.machinename, null, y.time, null
  from mytable y
  left join successes s
    on y.userdisplayname = s.userdisplayname
   and s.machinename = y.machinename
   and y.time = s.pending_time
 where s.connection_time is null
   and y.eventtype = 'PENDING'
union all
select * from successes
```

Note that the rows having nulls represent failed connection attempts.

Comment: I find it amazing that you're able to produce this so quickly and with so little context, but I have a few questions about what you wrote.

What's the story with the select nulls near the middle-bottom?  Also, did you mean to put those two where conditions together, instead of before that left join?

Comment: sure, want to start a chat?

Comment: I couldn't figure out the chat feature here soon enough, and I have to clock out for today.  I just had two brief questions: What's the story with the select nulls near the middle-bottom? Also, did you mean to put those two where conditions together, instead of before that left join?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The query block inside the with clause finds successful attempts. After the with clause the main query starts. The first thing I do is select from mytable where the event is pending and a matching connection is not found in the SUCCESSES query block result (using user, machine, and time as joins). Because they are not found, that means there was no eventual connection. So I select nulls in their place (there is nothing to grab). I then select everything from the successes block, via a union (grabbing hold of everything returned by the first query you see, contained inside the with clause).

Comment: In other words there are three steps and three independent queries: (1) obtain successful connections (2) obtain unsuccessful connections by looking for pending connections w/ no matches to the successes in step 1 and (3) return both those found in step 2 and step 1 as a combined result